# Play sound from a docker container in Headsets instead of laptop speakers

Tags: docker, opensuse

I am using openSUSE Leap 42.3 as host and I have this Dockerfile

```
FROM opensuse/tumbleweed                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

RUN zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys refresh
RUN zypper --non-interactive install --force-resolution alsa-utils
ADD test.wav /

CMD [ "/usr/bin/aplay", "/test.wav" ]
```

I build the image with this command

```
# docker image build -t aplay_test .
```

This is the build directory

```
$ ls -lh
total 9.2M
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio users  189 Sep 13 15:17 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio users 9.2M Sep 13 11:57 test.wav
```

When I run a container from that image,

```
# docker container run --rm --device /dev/snd aplay_test
```

the sound comes from the *laptop speakers*. But I would like that the sound comes from my **headset**.

If I execute the following command on my host

```
$ aplay test.wav
```

The sound comes from my **headset**.

How can I do that the sound comes from the **headset** inside the container?